# How do I make Graphql Code Generator for typescript make its enums into pascal case instead of snake case?

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, graphql-codegen, pascalcasing

Currently, the enums that Graphql Code Generator produces looks like this

```
export enum Test_Type {
    Test: 'TEST',
}
```

however I want the generated enums to be in pascal case like this:

```
export enum TestType {
  Test: 'TEST',
}
```

Edit, my codegen.yml:

```
overwrite: true
generates:
  src/graphql/generated/graphql.ts:
    schema: ${API_ENDPOINT}
    documents: ['src/graphql/**/*.graphql', 'src/graphql/**/*.gql']
    plugins:
      - 'typescript'
      - 'typescript-operations'
      - 'typescript-react-apollo'
  ./graphql.schema.json:
    schema: ${API_ENDPOINT}
    plugins:
      - 'introspection'
hooks:
  afterAllFileWrite:
    - prettier --write
```

The schema for the enum is

```
enum TEST_TYPE {
    TEST
}
```

Comment: https://www.graphql-code-generator.com/docs/getting-started/naming-convention? Please add the graphql schema containing the enum as well as your codegen.yaml configuration, otherwise we're unable to help you.

Comment: @Bergi I edited the post to my codegen.yml . I don't think I can provide the graphql schema since that's private. Is it necessary in this case since I'm asking a general question that's not related to the actual schemas?

Comment: Thanks. Not the entire schema, only the `enum TestType = TEST`

Comment: @Bergi I've included the schema for that enum. thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the [naming convention](https://www.graphql-code-generator.com/docs/getting-started/naming-convention) in config in your `codegen.yml` file.

```
config:
  namingConvention: change-case-all#pascalCase
```